# ClusteringComponents returning only ones

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to use ClusteringComponents without having to specify the number of clusters initially... so the algorithm can find itself the optimal number of clusters...

My data is of the form:

```
x=RandomReal[10, {100, 63}]
```

I am trying a command of the form:

```
cl = ClusteringComponents[RandomReal[10, {100, 63}], 
   DistanceFunction -> CorrelationDistance, Method -> "KMeans"];
```

The return value is wrong and is a bunch of 1's in a nested list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the `Level` as 1, you get two components:

```
x=RandomReal[10, {100, 63}];
cl = ClusteringComponents[RandomReal[10, {100, 63}], Automatic, 1, 
  DistanceFunction -> CorrelationDistance, Method -> "KMeans"]
(* {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2,
    1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2,
    2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1}*)

clx = Transpose[ConstantArray[cl, {63}]];
Overlay[{ArrayPlot[x, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1],
        ArrayPlot[clx, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1,
             ColorRules -> {1 -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Red], 
                           2 -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Green]}]}]
```

[image]

FWIW, if you remove the `DistanceFunction` option, you also get two clusters (at level 2):

```
clB = ClusteringComponents[RandomReal[10, {100, 63}], Method -> "KMeans"];
ComponentMeasurements[clB, "Label"]
(* {1 -> 1,2 -> 2} *)
Overlay[{ArrayPlot[x, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1],
         ArrayPlot[clB, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 1,
                   ColorRules -> {1 -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Red], 
                                  2 -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Green]}]}]
```

[image]